# File Reversing In C++

Tags: c++, file, copy

I am using this code to read from a file character by character and copying it to another file. I need the file to be reversed. So I am trying to set the file pointer to the beginning each time I copy a character.

```
using namespace std;

int main () {
  fstream myfile,infile;
  char c;
  infile.open("inputfile", ios::in);
  myfile.open ("outputfile",ios::out|ios::trunc);
  while(infile.get(c))
  {
      myfile<<c;
      myfile.seekp(0,myfile.beg);
  }
  infile.close();
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

But the output file is only having the first character I am copying. How can I resolve this.

Comment: There is no magical "insert mode" with files. By resetting the position to the start of the file, you're only overwriting the first character over and over again. You will have to stream the file contents in reverse instead.

Comment: Do you want to reverse it character by character or line by line?

Comment: by using `ios::out | ios::trunc`, you are overwriting on whatever you wrote onto the file each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the file in a vector as long as it is not too large and then write it out to outputfile:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  fstream myfile,infile;
  char c;
  vector<char> contentVector;
  infile.open("inputfile", ios::in);
  myfile.open ("outputfile",ios::out);
  while(infile.get(c)) {
    contentVector.push_back(c);
  }
  for (int i = contentVector.size() - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
    myfile << contentVector[i];
  }
  myfile << '\n';
  infile.close();
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `inputfile` has a reasonable size then you can use

```
// open inputfile
ifstream in("inputfile");
// read it to vector
vector<char> v( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
// create outputfile
ofstream out("outputfile");
// copy reversed vector to outputfile
copy(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), ostreambuf_iterator<char>(out));
```

If a size of `inputfile` can be hundreds of MiBs then you should write buffered I/O using `ifstream::seekg()` and `ifstream::read()` methods.